# How can I find the average score of each delivery within a sequence?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sequence

[image: Snapshot of DataFrame]

`score` is the score received on each delivery and `runs` are the cumulative of the score. `sequence` is the the 6 delivery sequence of `length/type` each over. I am trying to find the average score of each delivery  within a sequence across the whole dataset and the average runs for a sequence.

using this code I have got something like this but the problem is that each `length/type` does not repeat when it is grouped, so the cumulative of the averages, `runs` is not the correct 6 ball total:

```
df_seq=df_seq.reset_index()
df_sq = df_seq.groupby(['sequence', 'length/type']).agg({'score':'mean'})
df_sq['runs']=df_sq.groupby(['sequence'])['score'].cumsum()
df_sq
```

Here is the original dataframe `to_dict` with index reset:

```
{'Event_name': {0: 'fulham',
  1: 'fulham',
  2: 'fulham',
  3: 'fulham',
  4: 'fulham',
  5: 'fulham',
  6: 'fulham',
  7: 'fulham',
  8: 'fulham',
  9: 'fulham',
  10: 'fulham',
  11: 'fulham'},
 'Batfast_id': {0: 'bfs00200002',
  1: 'bfs00200002',
  2: 'bfs00200002',
  3: 'bfs00200002',
  4: 'bfs00200002',
  5: 'bfs00200002',
  6: 'bfs00200002',
  7: 'bfs00200002',
  8: 'bfs00200002',
  9: 'bfs00200002',
  10: 'bfs00200002',
  11: 'bfs00200002'},
 'Session_no': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1},
 'Overs': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 0,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1},
 'Deliveries_faced': {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 4,
  5: 5,
  6: 6,
  7: 7,
  8: 8,
  9: 9,
  10: 10,
  11: 11},
 'score': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 6.0,
  5: 4.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0},
 'runs': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 6.0,
  5: 10.0,
  6: 10.0,
  7: 10.0,
  8: 10.0,
  9: 10.0,
  10: 10.0,
  11: 10.0},
 'delivery_type': {0: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  1: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  2: 'Slow Straight',
  3: 'Extra Slow Off Spin',
  4: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  5: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  6: 'Extra Slow Off Spin',
  7: 'Extra Slow Off Spin',
  8: 'Slow Straight',
  9: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  10: 'Extra Slow Off Spin',
  11: 'Extra Slow Off Spin'},
 'length': {0: 'Yorker',
  1: 'Yorker',
  2: 'Yorker',
  3: 'Yorker',
  4: 'Yorker',
  5: 'Yorker',
  6: 'Yorker',
  7: 'Yorker',
  8: 'Yorker',
  9: 'Yorker',
  10: 'Yorker',
  11: 'Yorker'},
 'length/type': {0: 'ES_LS_Y',
  1: 'ES_LS_Y',
  2: 'S_S_Y',
  3: 'ES_OS_Y',
  4: 'ES_LS_Y',
  5: 'ES_LS_Y',
  6: 'ES_OS_Y',
  7: 'ES_OS_Y',
  8: 'S_S_Y',
  9: 'ES_LS_Y',
  10: 'ES_OS_Y',
  11: 'ES_OS_Y'},
 'sequence': {0: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  1: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  2: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  3: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  4: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  5: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  6: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  7: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  8: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  9: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  10: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  11: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y'}}
```

Below is the perfect example because there are only 2 overs of this sequence in the data set:
[image: Example sequence]

The result I'm trying to get from this sequence is an average of the score for each delivery and the cumulative average runs as follows:

```
                                                           score runs
sequence                                      length/type       
ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F ES_LS_F     0.0   0.0
                                                ES_LS_F     2.0   2.0
                                                ES_LS_F     0.0   2.0
                                                ES_LS_F     0.0   2.0
                                                ES_LS_F     2.0   4.0
                                                ES_LS_F     0.0   4.0
```

ie the `score` for the first delivery would be `(0+0)/2 = 0`. the second would be `(0+4)/2 = 2` and so on. `runs` are the cumulative of this. The current solution is `(4+4)/12` giving 0.67 as an average score to every delivery, this is not correct.

```
df_reg['sequence'] = (df_reg.groupby(["Event_name", "Batfast_id", "Session_no", "Overs"])["length/type"]
                       .apply(lambda x: ",".join(x)).loc[lambda x: x.str.count(",") == 5]

                   )
```

If I was able to uniquely number each delivery in the sequence I would be able to do it.

Comment: reset index, groupby(['sequence', 'length/type']), agg('mean'). If you provide the dataframe constructor with example data I can show you.

Comment: @PatrykKowalski I tried something like this but there was a problem. Please see the details in the question. I've also added a 'to_dict' sample of the data

Comment: @PatrykKowalski do you need any more info?

Comment: After consideration I do not understand what you're trying to accomplish, or how you got the result you showed as intended.
Average score of ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y / ES_LS_Y is 2.5, not 2.
Why is it repeated twice in the result, with score 2 and then score 3?

Comment: @PatrykKowalski you are right, I have changed the example screen grab to be accurate. Please note though the example is not real results just an example of what I want it to look like. I want the average score of each delivery in the sequence but any repeated 'length/type' to be presented so that I can get the cumulative sum of all the average scores within the over to get a total, which is what the 'runs' column is. I don't want the average score of the over.

Comment: @PatrykKowalski it might help to add, this is so that I can plot a line chart for each sequence

Comment: It would be much clearer if you actually took the time to prepare the example result matching your data. Now I need to guess if that's what you intended. I added the answer, I hope that's what the idea was.

Comment: @PatrykKowalski have you seen the edits I have made

Comment: I did, I gave up on this. The question is too complex and not clear and I already put lots of time into what the question was at the time. My suggestion is - if you need help, try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Get rid of the context of the problem, just make a smallest and easiest example possible that illustrates what you need to get done. And then repost it.

Comment: @PatrykKowalski I'm sorry that it was not clear. I've added how I made the column `sequence`. If you just know how to uniquely number each delivery in the sequence then your method would work. If it is not a quick solution then don't worry, I don't wish to take up your time.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is not really clear, but I'll give it a try.
First you want to establish what are the averages for sequence, length/type.

```
df_grp = df.groupby(['sequence', 'length/type'])[['score']].mean()
```

Then add those calculations to your original structure

```
df2 = df.set_index(['sequence', 'length/type'])
df2 = df2[[]].merge(df_grp, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This gets us:

```
                                                           score
sequence                                      length/type       
ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y ES_LS_Y        2.5
                                              ES_LS_Y        2.5
                                              ES_LS_Y        2.5
                                              ES_LS_Y        2.5
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0
                                              S_S_Y          0.0
ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y ES_LS_Y        0.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0
                                              S_S_Y          0.0
```

Now you just need to calculate the cumulative sum for each sequence.

```
df2_runs = df2.groupby(df2.index)[['score']].cumsum().rename(columns={"score" : "runs"})
df2['runs'] = df2_runs.runs
```

The final result is

```
                                                           score  runs
sequence                                      length/type             
ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y ES_LS_Y        2.5   2.5
                                              ES_LS_Y        2.5   5.0
                                              ES_LS_Y        2.5   7.5
                                              ES_LS_Y        2.5  10.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0   0.0
                                              S_S_Y          0.0   0.0
ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y ES_LS_Y        0.0   0.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0   0.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0   0.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0   0.0
                                              ES_OS_Y        0.0   0.0
                                              S_S_Y          0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry it is not clear. I'm having a problem with step 2. It throws up this error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Most likely in your source data there are some missing values. Missing value is interpreted as a float. In that case you'd need to deal with the missing data first.

Comment: You can check if the solution works on the data sample you have provided - then we'd be sure the issue is with different data

Comment: It works when you change the groupby in the 3rd step to 'sequence' instead of df2.index. However there is an issue where when every delivery in a sequence is the same it repeats more than 6 times. I have put a snapshot of this issue in the question

Comment: Grouping by index means grouping by sequence, length/type, and is not the same as you did. That's what caused duplicates on merging. You apparently have missing data in the length/type column.

Comment: `df2=df_reg.copy()
df2= df2[df2['sequence'].notna()]
df2 = df2.set_index(['sequence', 'length/type'])
df2 = df2[[]].merge(df_grp, left_index=True, right_index=True)`
I have done this for step 2 to remove missing data. This is when the duplicates still occur

Comment: I have found a real example that was easy to calculate and edited the question to show exactly what I want. I hope this makes it clearer

Comment: is what I want actually possible?